# Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew"

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am developing an android app with React Native and Expo, last week I built the app and everything was ok, but now I try to rebuild my app and I get this error.

Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android

*Here there is some more code*

[stderr]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.

[stderr]

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

[stderr]

> Compilation error. See log for more details

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 6m 17s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

I deleted node_modules then reinstalled with npm install, but didnt work.
Some webpages on internet didnt wok either XD.

Comment: did you figured it out  @Pedro Luis D L